# Error message when installing Ruby from Command Line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am taking Lynda's Ruby on Rails course and am attempting to install the Ruby on Rails gem.
I am using Windows 7 Enterprise.
I have installed Ruby version 2.3.3p222 and the Ruby DevKit.
I have gems version 2.6.11.
I am attempting to install RoR using the command using this command:

C:>gem install rails --version 5.0.0

This returns an error message:

```
ERROR: Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/li/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-
1.2.1/ext/nio4r
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170416-5208-120ozvl.rb extconf.rb 
checking for unistd.h...***extconf.rb failed***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably a lack of necessary 
libraries and or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may 
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
```

...and so on.  I've found many people with similar problems on this site, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove 64-bit DevKit and install the 32-bit. It should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot!